# The best way to communicate between multiple iPhones/iPads in a card game

Tags: iphone, networking, cocos2d-iphone

I have been looking around for information about this topic but not found what i need.

Here is the scenario, i am planning a card based game (cocos2d) where the idea is that up to four players should be able to play.

One player will hand out the cards to all four and then they play. Next round the next player should do this and so on..

On the screen i would like the actual player to see his/her own cards as well as the others cards that they have played out meaning that each player should see the others active cards.

I would like to ask the following:

1. How would be the best way of implementing this from a communication point of view?
2. Would this go via game center?

A reference to information is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peer-2-Peer has advantages (scalability, no server cost), but several disadvantages:

- you need lots of communication with more than 2 players
- cheating
- handling of dropping players
- master election (dealing cards, decisions etc)

[iScat](http://mobilebits.de/Games/Default.aspx?Game=iSkat&Category=MobileBits) from Mobilebits for example uses an authorative (client/server) based approach.

- [Photon](http://www.exitgames.com/)
- free for up to 100 CCUs (concurrent users)
- support iOS, Android, HTML5, Flash, ...

You can easily combine this central matchmaking with gamecenter as well.

Answer (score 1):

I always suggest to try to stay peer-to-peer in communications. This generally avoids bottlenecks and single-point-of-failures, in other words it scales.

In you case i would set up an Reliable UDP connection and use a reactor to unify network and gui events.

Obviously this does not resolve the problem with Service advertising beyond the local network, in this case an index server can not be avoided.

I am aware that this is only an arhitectural indication; I can't help you more to the point because of my lack of experience with cocos2d but I hope this can help anyway